Firestore prevent snapshots firing prior to batch being commited
I am currently experiencing an issue where I am listening to a user to be added to a group and to create subscriptions whenever a group is created like so:
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('users')
.doc(ref.read(AuthService.userProvider).value!.uid)
.collection('groups')
.snapshots()
.listen((event) {
  for (DocumentChange change in event.docChanges) { 
    if (change.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
      _groupSubscriptions.add(FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('groups')
      .doc(change.doc.id)
      .snapshots()
      .listen(
        (event) {
          print(event.metadata.isFromCache);
          groups[change.doc.id] = (Group.fromJson(event.data()!), event.id);
          setState(() {});
        },
        cancelOnError: false,
        onError: (_) {
          print("Error");
        },
      ));
    }
  }
});

This errors with invalid permissions to read the group. My firestore rule for this is as follows:
match /groups/{groupId} {
  allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(groupId)/members/$(request.auth.uid));
}

I am batch writing the creation of the group addition to the members collection of said group and addition to the users group collections as follows:
var batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
var user = ref.watch(AuthService.userProvider).value!;

var group = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc();

batch.set(
  group,
  {
     'title': controller.text,
     'created_at': Timestamp.now(),
     'last_message': Message(
       content: '',
       type: MessageType.text,
       sender: user.uid,
       sentAt: DateTime.now(),
     ).toJson(),
   },
 );

 batch.set(
   group.collection('members').doc(user.uid),
   {
      'joined_at': Timestamp.now(),
   },
 );

 batch.set(
   group.collection('admins').doc(user.uid),
     {
       'joined_at': Timestamp.now(),
     },
 );

 batch.set(
   FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection('users')
     .doc(user.uid)
     .collection('groups')
     .doc(group.id),
  {
    'joined_at': Timestamp.now(),
  },
);

await batch.commit();

The problem is as follows, the nested listener in the first snippet appears to trigger before the batch is committed to fire store. I have debugged this through the use of "event.metadata.isFromCache". The callback only fires when this value is true. I can get the event to fire when I change the firestore rule to "allow read: if true;". Finally if I remount the component or add a delay before adding the listener (1 second or so) the data is loaded perfectly normally without errors, which is what leads me to believe this is being fired before the data is committed. Finally I am testing this on the Firebase Emulator which I know does not have complete parity with Firebase but I would ideally like to continue using the emulator and have not tried on actual Firestore.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. I apologise for the large code snippets but feel they were necessary to demonstrate my current setup. Finally I would also be open to suggestions on how to restructure my database as I am relatively new to Firebase && Firestore.

If I understand correctly you may be seeing the local write operations before they are committed to the database on the server.
In that case you should indeed see that the isFromCache and hasPendingWrites flags are set to true for those snapshots. You can ignore those snapshots if needed, as shown in the documentation on events for local changes.
